# Does [m] sound influence [ɑ] sound?

Tags: pronunciation

> . . . calm . . . heart . . . heart . . . half . . . [[audio source]](http://audioscraps.tistory.com/132)

The first [ɑ] sound in calm seems to be made at noticeably nearer the middle [[IPA]](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ipa) than the others. Am I hearing right? If yes, is it because of [m] sound that is made in front?

Comment: That is the same /ɑ/ sound you hear in _car_, _mar_, and _tar_. I don't think the sound can be explain only by the presence of the M in _calm_.

Comment: Please fix the audio source link.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have an acute ear: yes, this speaker's pronunciation of /kɑːlm/ approaches /kɔːm/. I would guess that this is because her /l/ is reduced (as it is for many speakers) to a 'glide' before /m/—/lm/ is almost /ʊm/—and that pulls her /ɑː/ towards the front.

/lm/ is not a frequent syllable termination in English, and different speakers have different approaches. Some employ a glide, as here; others drop the /l/ altogether and say /kɑːm/, /pɑːm/, /sɑːm/ for *calm*, *palm*, *psalm*.

Comment: The OED gives /kɑːm/, which is how I pronounce it. No /l/.

Comment: Me, too; but back in the Dark Ages when I was a child that was regarded as substandard over here. Twain, I seem to recall, makes a point of noting his characters' pronunciation as *psa'm*.

Comment: @StoneyB, Thank you very much. I’ve been wondering over a year, but anybody says ‘they are the same.’ Now you solved my long puzzlement. Thank you.