# /kɑlm/ vs /kɑːm/

Tags: pronunciation, vowels, ipa

. . . calm . . .calm . . . [[audio source]](http://audioscraps.tistory.com/134)

•   (UK) IPA: /kɑːm/, X-SAMPA: /kA:m/
•   (US) IPA: /kɑm/, /kɑlm/, X-SAMPA: /kAhm/, /kAlm/  [[wiktionary.org]](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/calm)

The first *calm* seems to be [[kɑlm]](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/1418/does-m-sound-influence-sound), and the latter [kɑːm]. Do I hear right or both sound [kɑlm]?

Comment: I think you're hearing correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This article](http://www.deimel.org/language/l.htm) has an extended list of words with silent and pronounced "l".

For a language learner, the simplest rule is remembering some most commonly used words that do have silent "l":

- **-alk**: *talk, walk, chalk*;
- **-ould**: *could, should, would*;
- **-alf**: *half*;
- **-alm**: *calm, palm*;

Pronouncing the rest of the words with "l" articulated is not necessarily grammatical, but certainly more accepted/understood by native speakers.

Also, see [this question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/100504/why-is-the-l-silent-when-pronouncing-salmon) on ELU for more details.

Update: as @tchrist noticed, words with *-alm* may be subject of variations.

Comment: Um, no.  Neither *calm* nor *palm* has a “silent L” in my own speech.  *Calm* is like the start of **“call me** a taxi”, and *palm* is like the start of **“Paul might** call me.”  The *L* is not suppressed for me:  neither in the phrases nor in the single words. That’s why it is present in the IPA above. Mine might be closer to the CLOTH vowel, though.